# transfer data from table to another with adding other information

Tags: erlang

I have this record

```
-record(transaction, {id, transaction_code, operation_code, ip_access).
```

and with this code I create a clone of this table named transaction_backup

```
mnesia:create_table(transaction_backup,[{disc_copies, [node()]},{attributes, record_info(fields, transaction)},
    {record_name, transaction}]).
```

and with this code I transfer data from **transaction** to **transaction_backup**

```
mnesia:transaction(fun() ->
  Records = mnesia:select(transaction, [{'_', [], ['$_']}]),
  [ok = mnesia:write(transaction_backup, Record, write) || Record <- Records]
end).
```

mean if the table transaction contains this values :

```
1   E001  F200  127.0.01
2   E102  F300  127.0.01
3   E105  F402  127.0.01
```

The table transaction_backup will contain the same thing

```
1   E001  F200  127.0.01
2   E102  F300  127.0.01
3   E105  F402  127.0.01
```

now I want to create a table transaction_backup but this time the table transaction_backup has other fields   named **idback** which will be the unique id of transaction_backup

so we should create transaction_backup in another way and not like this

```
   mnesia:create_table(transaction_backup,[{disc_copies, [node()]},{attributes, record_info(fields, transaction)},
        {record_name, transaction}]).
```

and the value of **idback** will automatically increment  using this code

```
idback= next_id(tranasction_backup),

next_id(T) ->
    mnesia:dirty_update_counter(counter, T, 1).
```

so when we transfer data from transaction to transaction_backup whe shoud make something like this I think

```
 mnesia:transaction(fun() ->
      Records = mnesia:select(transaction, [{'_', [], ['$_']}]),



F = fun() ->

                      Idback= next_id(tranasction_backup),

                        Trans = #tranasaction_backup{idback= Idback},
                        mnesia:write(Trans),
                        {ok};

        end,
    {atomic, Val} = mnesia:transaction(F),
    Val.



[ok = mnesia:write(transaction_backup, Record, write) || Record <- Records]
    end).
```

so The table transaction_backup will contain this value

```
1  1   E001  F200  127.0.01
2  2   E102  F300  127.0.01
3  3   E105  F402  127.0.01
```

I want to know how can we create the table transaction_backup

as I said I try with :

```
 mnesia:create_table(transaction_backup,[{disc_copies, [node()]},{attributes, record_info(fields, transaction)},
        {record_name, transaction}]).
```

but in my case the table **transaction_backup** has more **fields** than the table **transaction** which   named **idback**

so in order to create the table `transaction_backup` we should try in another way

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have the same transaction record. You need to create a new record with idback.
Either you need to copy all the elements from transaction to transaction_backup record before writing into the backup table. Or you can do

```
 Records = mnesia:select(transaction, [{'_', [], ['$_']}]),
```

`[ok = mnesia:write(erlang:setelement(1, erlang:insert_element(2, Record, next_id(tranasction_backup)), transaction_backup) || Record <- Records]`

The above works only on R16A onwards. Otherwise you can do

```
     [ok = mnesia:write(to_backup(Record, next_id(tranasction_backup))) 
|| Record <- Records].
```

and to_backup looks like

```
    to_backup(Record, Id) ->
        [_H| List] = tuple_to_list(Record),
        list_to_tuple([transaction_backup, x| List]).
```

Comment: when I use your code I have this error function insert_element/3 undefined